# Conditional Probability of A given B

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Very basic question, but
If A and B are independent events, 
then is the Probability of A given B has occurred = Zero or Probability of A?

and why?

Comment: What do you think?  What is the definition of "Independent"?

Comment: That the occurrence of one event does not affect the other.

Comment: Ok, can you express that mathematically?

Comment: So shouldn't the answer be Zero? Because the Intersection of the two sets is empty?

Comment: Mutually exclusive events are not independent.  Think of tossing a penny and tossing a dime.  Knowing the penny came up $H$ doesn't say anything about the dime.  That;s what independent means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional probability is given by $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$. And events $A$ and $B$ are independent if $P(A|B) = P(A)$ (in words, the probability that $A$ occurs given that $B$ occurs is that same as $A$ occurs with regardless of knowledge of $B$). Equivalently, $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$.

So the answer is $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} = P(A)$. Not $P(A)=0.$

If you have events with $P(A\cap B) = 0$ and $P(A \cup B) = 1$, they are called mutually exclusive. In that case you could conclude that $P(A|B) = 0$. But mutually exclusive events are highly dependent.

Mutually exclusive events are in some sense the opposite of independent events. If $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, and you know whether $A$ occurred, then you know **for sure** whether $B$ occurred. Whereas if $A$ and $B$ are independent events, if you know that $A$ occurred, you have **no information** about whether $B$ occurred. For independent events, you have $P(A|B)=P(A).$